# How to specify 2 attributes with input_html in simple_form 2.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

In a Rails app, we would like to specify both rows and value for a text column in simple form. It is easy to do with one:

```
<%=f.input :column, :input_html => {:rows => 5}%>
<%=f.input :column, :input_html => {:value => 'abc'}%>
```

We tried the following for 2 attributes:

```
<%=f.input :column, :input_html => {:rows => 5, :value => 'abc' }%>
```

Only the :value works and there is only single row instead of 5. The following causes syntax error:

```
<%=f.input :column, :input_html => {{:rows => 5}, {:value => 'abc' }}%>
```

What's the right way to specify 2 attributes in input_html? Or it is not achievable?

UPDATE:
Here is the html source for the text column:

```
<div class="input string optional onboard_engine_config_argument_value"><label class="string optional control-label" for="onboard_engine_config_argument_value">变量值</label><input class="string optional span12" id="onboard_engine_config_argument_value" name="onboard_engine_config[argument_value]" rows="5" size="50" type="text" value=" ....."</div>
```

The value = "..." is a extremely long text which is a html.erb file and is displayed not in its original order. We are trying to make it displayed in its original order.

Comment: What's the datatype of this `column`? It only generates a textarea if the db column is `text` (for postgres)

Comment: What is the generated output?

Comment: Not sure what's your question. It was all the text in one row instead of in 5 rows.

Comment: What is the generated html

Comment: I see. just updated the post with the source html. There is rows=5 in the source. But it is only a single row in html.

Comment: Yeah, that's because it's an input, not a textarea. The datatype of the column cannot be text if it only generates an input.

Comment: Try adding 'as: :text' `<%= input :column, input_html: {..}, as: :text %>`

Comment: It works. I will mark it if you post it again as answer. thanks.

Comment: Good to hear, have made a proper answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it doesn't seem to work is because simple_form generates an input instead of a textarea. To force it to render a textarea do it like this.

```
<%= input :column, input_html: { rows: 4, value: "some long text"}, as: :text %>
```

The `as: :text` part forces it to render a textarea.